# Snowflake: Item contains without flatten

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a `JSON` and need to check if an object exists in the array or not. I'm using snowflake. I know how to do it with `FLATTEN`, but it's too slow. (too many rows * flatten = slow).

Any ideas on how to check existence without `flatten`

For instance, here's the array

```json
[
    {
        "code": "NOTE",
        "contactValues": [],
        "options": ["MY_NOTE"],
        "value": null
    }, {
        "code": "MUST_READ",
        "contactValues": [],
        "options": ["FYI"],
        "value": null
    }
]
```

and need to check if the item with `code` = `NOTE` exists in the array `without flatten`.

This one works too, but have to search the whole item. I don't have the whole item, know only the `code` value

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS(TO_VARIANT(PARSE_JSON('{
        "code": "NOTE",
        "contactValues": [],
        "options": ["MY_NOTE"],
        "value": null
    }')), parse_json('[ {
        "code": "NOTE",
        "contactValues": [],
        "options": ["MY_NOTE"],
        "value": null
    }, {
        "code": "MUST_READ",
        "contactValues": [],
        "options": ["FYI"],
        "value": null
    }
]')) AS Result
```

Comment: Do you store those in VARIANT or are they strings? For strings you could consider regexp, but I'm not sure if it would be any faster...